# GWT DockLayoutPanel oddness

Tags: gwt, docklayoutpanel

I'm using a DockLayoutPanel for my application.  It worked great when I just had widgets in the North, West, and East.  When I added one to the South, though, it didn't wind up where I expected - it's more center than south.

```
    private DockLayoutPanel mainPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    mainPanel.addNorth(topPanel, 15);
    mainPanel.addWest(resultsGrid, 65);
    mainPanel.addEast(wcFlexTable, 35);
    mainPanel.addSouth(pager, 10);


    // Associate the Main panel with the HTML host page. 
    RootLayoutPanel.get().setStylePrimaryName("rootLayoutPanel");
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
```

It is rendered as below - you can see the Pager element, not where I expect it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that I added the South element *after* East and West.  By moving it to before East and West, everything displays as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the units you're using, the south pane seems to me to be correctly positioned, with the pager being at the top of the south pane, the default position for elements within their containers.

Comment: I'm confused, though - it's not below the East and West panes; the bottom appears to be even with them.  Shouldn't it be below them?  If' I"m misunderstanding, can you suggest how I might alter my settings?

Comment: It's perfectly expected, considering the order in which you're adding panes. Try adding the south pane after north.